# onchange function not running for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a read-only textbox (`sum`) and whenever its value changes, I want a second read-only textbox (`totalcost`) to update its value.

Here's what I have, but for some reason it's not working. All of the references are correct, am I missing something basic?

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[name="totalCPC"]').on('change', function() {
    var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]:checked').val());
    var cpc = parseFloat($('input[id="sum"]').val());
    var noc = parseFloat($('input[id="numberofclickstextbox"]').val());
    $('#totalcost').val(function() {
      return ((noc * cpc) *pc).toFixed(2);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: How is a readonly textbox supposed to have its value changed by a user? That's the only thing that will fire a change event automatically.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh i see - I have a function that updates the readonly textbox value, how do I get another function to fire once that value is updated?

Comment: As the answer below shows, after your method changes the value, you need to `trigger('change')` to generate an event.

Comment: In your function that updates the textbox, call the function. No need to use events at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [trigger change event](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('#totalcost').val(function() {
  return ((noc * cpc) *pc).toFixed(2);
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: where do I declare the variables?

Comment: In that place where you update field value. After .val(newValue)